# How do I get the name of my application when Impersonating in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

How do I get the name of my application when Impersonating in .NET. I don't have any preference for what .NET language you like VB.NET or C#. I am essentially doing (excuse VB.NET here):

```
theImpersonator = New Impersonator("username", "domain", "password")
Dim finfo As New FileInfo(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName)
Dim appname As String = finfo.Name.Substring(0, finfo.Name.IndexOf("."))
```

Without using "New Impersonator(...)" everything is fine. When I use the "Impersonator" I get:

```
Access is denied
   at System.Diagnostics.ProcessManager.OpenProcess(Int32 processId, Int32 access, Boolean throwIfExited)
   at System.Diagnostics.NtProcessManager.GetModuleInfos(Int32 processId, Boolean firstModuleOnly)
   at System.Diagnostics.NtProcessManager.GetFirstModuleInfo(Int32 processId)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.get_MainModule()
```

How do I find out the name of my application .exe file when I am using Impersonation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the person you are impersonating does not have access to the running file. Verify that it isn't in some folder unavailable to the impersonated user. For instance, running on a server a normal user does not have access. Try settings the user as a local admin on the computer or just granting him access to the folder.

An easier way would be to just:

```
Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName
```

I don't think you should use a `FileInfo`, that is slow and needs rights.
You can use the System.IO.Path static class instead

Comment: hmm, interesting idea. He probably does not - can he figure out some other way which exe is currently running?

Comment: Perfect! Just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about Impersonator, but this works in most of my applications (even WPF apps).

```
    string name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(
                    System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExecutablePath);
```

Comment: Interesting idea but I believe I will get the same "Access is denied" because the impersonator doesn't have access to the file as @Oskar pointed out. Thank you for the suggestion. <UpVote>

Comment: @Denis I don't think this would yield that error. Neither `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension` nor `System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExecutablePath` needs permissions to that directory